# Formatting spaces between two listed arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, printf

How can I format this so the outputted table is inline and the spaces are equal?

```
public class jh {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int [] quantity = {31, 10, 30, 19, 25, 80}; 
    
    String [] product = {"Milk", "Eggs", "Cereal", "Apples", "Cheese","Chicken"}; 
    
    System.out.println("Index  Product    Quantity");
    for (int i=0; i<6;i++)
    { 
    System.out.println(i+1+"  "+product [i]+"  "+quantity[i]); 
    
    
}

}
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `printf`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.out.format` or `String.format` to specify a width for each element.

```java
System.out.println("Index  Product    Quantity");
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
    System.out.format("%-6s %-10s %-8s%n", i + 1, product[i], quantity[i]); 
}
```